# Need to count the quantity of a specific number in a column, with a filter

Tags: r, tidyr, tidy

I used data from 2 data sets that were part of "nycflights13" and used it to find out what was the oldest flight out of a particular airport. Now I need to find out how many of that type of plane flew out of the airport. I'm not sure how to do this. I tried using table() but that gave me an output of 1.

```
library(nycflights13)

library(conflicted)  
suppressMessages(conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr"))  
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse)) 

data("flights") 

theflights <- 
   flights %>% 
   filter(origin == "JFK") %>%
   select (tailnum)  

 data("planes") 

 x <- inner_join(theflights, planes) %>%  
  filter(year == min(year, na.rm = T)) %>%  
  select(tailnum) %>%  
  distinct()
x
```

Here is the original code for the first part of the problem. I think the reason that table() didn't work is because I created x to be a single value. How do I find out how many times that type of plane flew out of a specific airport?

Comment: Can you show the code that you used for `table` ? `x` has only one row. what do you want to use that for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I think it sounds like you're asking how to get the number of flights with the tailnum you stored in `x`, flying out of `"JFK"`? If that's the case, you can filter based on those two conditions then get the number of rows:

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

filter(flights, tailnum == "N381AA" & origin == "JFK") %>% 
  nrow()
#> [1] 22
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>